# CoordinatorLayout causes next fragment bottom part cut / out of screen

Tags: android, fragment, android-coordinatorlayout

fragment transaction from Fragment1 to  Fragment2 causes bottom aligned button in Fragment2 cut / out of the screen, if Fragment1 has  CoordinatorLayout & CollapsingToolbarLayout.

the issue in Fragment2 disappears if  I replace CoordinatorLayout with LinearLayout

tried removing fragment transaction custom animation. still not working

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="ltr">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="259dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentScrim="#fff"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                android:id="@+id/autoScrollViewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <!--toolbar content-->


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- content-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    tools:context=".RFQFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <!--toolbar content-->
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">


<!-- content-->


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_enabled"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/enable_able_text_color_selector"
        android:textSize="18dp"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" solved the issue

Comment: Had a similar issue where the toolbar in fragment one would disappear during the fragment transaction animation to fragment two where I defined a coordinator layout. This resolved my issue as well.